# How can I create a Unity launcher for Shotwell Photo Viewer?

Tags: unity, launcher, shotwell

The best piece of software for simple cropping of images seems (to me) to be Shotwell Photo Viewer, especially as I find GIMP's cropping methods (AutoCropping & Zealous Cropping) incomprehensible.

I can start Shotwell Photo Viewer by right clicking the image file (in Nautilus). However, there are 2 Desktop Configuration Files for Shotwell & 1 for Shotwell Viewer, all loading Shotwell Photo Manager. I also don't see any shell script or executable for Shotwell Photo Viewer.

Can anybody supply a Desktop Configuration File for Shotwell Photo Viewer? Alternatively, can anybody point me to the shell script or executable for Shotwell Photo Viewer (in the Ubuntu Precise file system)?

Answer (score 0):

The executable file for Shotwell Photo Viewer is located in `/usr/bin` directory. You cen test this from terminal using the following command:

```
whereis shotwell
```

Now, to create an entry for Shotwell Photo Viewer on your Unity launcher, simply open Shotwell Photo Viewer, then right click on its picture on the launcher and select **Lock to Launcher**.

Comment: If I type '/usr/bin/shotwell (in Terminal), it brings up the Photo Manager not the Photo Viewer. I don't want to put an icon (for Shotwell Photo Viewer) in the Unity launcher: I want to create a Desktop Configuration File for the Photo Viewer so that I can put that icon in a Drawer (on the Desktop): Drawers is an addon allowing for functions like putting a number of icons (to start apps) in a named drawer - I have so many apps (each with its own start icon) that without Drawers I fill up the Desktop or have far too many in Unity's launcher.

Comment: @JohnRose If you want to open Shotwell Photo Viewer with a specific image, then use `/usr/bin/shotwell /path/to/image`, or simply `shotwell /path/to/image`. The same command can be used in the .desktop file.

Comment: I don't want to open Shotwell Photo Viewer witha specifiic image: I can do that from Nautilus. I want the desktop configuration file (for Shotwell Photo Viewer) to open without loading an image. To repeat my question: Can anybody supply a Desktop Configuration File for Shotwell Photo Viewer? Alternatively,can anybody point me to the shell script or executable for Shotwell Photo Viewer (in the Ubuntu Precise file system)?